# How can I move a method from form1 to a new class file with parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a new class file: And i want to move the method DirSearch in form1 to this new class file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Search_Text_In_Files
{
    class Search_Engine
    {

    }
}
```

In form1

```
void DirSearch(string rootDirectory, string filesExtension, string textToSearch, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> filePathList = new List<string>();
    List<string> restrictedFiles = new List<string>();
    int overallfiles = 0;
    int numberoffiles = 0;
    int numberofdirs = 0;

    try
    {
        var dirs = F(textBox3.Text, 0);
        var deep = (from d in dirs
                orderby d.Item2 descending
                select d).FirstOrDefault().Item2;
        filePathList = SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinct(rootDirectory, null).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        string ad = err.ToString();
    }
    foreach (string file in filePathList)
    {
        try
        {
            _busy.WaitOne();
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
            List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();
            int var = File.ReadAllText(file).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;
            overallfiles++;
            if (var == 1)
            {
                numberoffiles++;
                prog.Add(new MyProgress { Report1 = file, Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString() });
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, prog);
            }
            numberofdirs++;
            label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                label1.Text = numberofdirs.ToString();
                label1.Visible = true;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            restrictedFiles.Add(file);
            continue;
        }
    }

}
```

My question is in case I need to pass textBoxes or labels how should I do it? Just add more textBox and label controls parameters to the method in the new class?

I just want to arrange my form1 code.

Comment: what is it you are trying to do..? can you please edit this question and state what it is you are trying to do..?

Comment: @MethodMan Updated my question.

Comment: Can you please mark one of the below answers as the accepted answers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write a class that isn't coupled with your form (or any other type of UI) you should pass the data values and not the controls. This would keep your new class reusable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're describing, but it's not going to accomplish much. `DirSearch` depends entirely on controls in your form. If you just move the method to another class it's still going to depend on that form.

In addition, those controls are likely `private` which means your other class won't be able to access them. You could change their access to `internal` but it doesn't get you anything at all.

It would make more sense to write a class that handles details like searching files but doesn't interact directly with the controls. That class could execute the search and expose properties or raise events indicating its progress, and raise an event when it's done. Your form creates that class, tells it what search to execute, and then responds to those events by updating its controls.

Another way of saying the same thing: How would you write your `Search_Engine` class if it wasn't in a forms app? What if the same class needed to work in a console app too? Write the class like that. Assume that the only way that class can communicate is with the properties it exposes and the events it raises. The class that uses `Search_Engine` is entirely responsible for determining if or how those events are somehow communicated to the UI.